# How to list all tables in psql?

Tags: database, postgresql, command, psql, dbtable

I would like to list all tables in the `liferay` database in my PostgreSQL install. How do I do that?

I would like to execute `SELECT * FROM applications;` in the `liferay` database. `applications` is a table in my liferay db. How is this done?

Here's a list of all my databases:

```
postgres=# \list
                              List of databases
Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
 -----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 liferay   | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |             |             | liferay=CTc/postgres
 lportal   | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)

postgres=#
```

Answer (score 245, accepted):

If you wish to list *all* tables, you must use:

```
\dt *.*
```

to indicate that you want all tables *in all schemas*. This will include tables in `pg_catalog`, the system tables, and those in `information_schema`. There's no built-in way to say "all tables in all user-defined schemas"; you can, however, set your `search_path` to a list of all schemas of interest before running `\dt`.

You may want to do this programmatically, in which case `psql` backslash-commands won't do the job. This is where [the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) comes to the rescue. To list tables:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public';
```

BTW, if you ever want to see what `psql` is doing in response to a backslash command, run `psql` with the `-E` flag. eg:

```
$ psql -E regress    
regress=# \list
********* QUERY **********
SELECT d.datname as "Name",
       pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner",
       pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding",
       d.datcollate as "Collate",
       d.datctype as "Ctype",
       pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d
ORDER BY 1;
**************************
```

so you can see that `psql` is searching `pg_catalog.pg_database` when it gets a list of databases. Similarly, for tables within a given database:

```
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','')
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

It's preferable to use the SQL-standard, portable `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` instead of the Pg system catalogs where possible, but sometimes you need Pg-specific information. In those cases it's fine to query the [system catalogs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html) directly, and `psql -E` can be a helpful guide for how to do so.

Comment: `information_schema.tables` includes views for some reason. (In PostgreSQL 9.2, anyway.)

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, with `table_type = 'VIEW'`, so they're easy to exclude. In general SQL tries to treat views the same as tables as much as possible.

Answer (score 98):

Connect to the database, then list the tables:

```
\c liferay
\dt
```

That's how I do it anyway.

You can combine those two commands onto a single line, if you prefer:

```
\c liferay \dt
```

Comment: You actually want `\dt *.*` if not all tables of interest are on the `search_path`.

Answer (score 15):

To see the public tables you can do

list tables

```
\dt
```

list table, view, and access privileges

```
\dp or \z
```

or just the table names

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'public';
```

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Query, you can write this code:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='YOUR_TABLE_SCHEME';
```

Replace your table scheme with YOUR_TABLE_SCHEME;

Example:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='eLearningProject';
```

To see all scheme and all tables, there is no need of where clause:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables
```

Answer (score 2):

A one-line example is:

```
\dt schemaname.*
```

In your scenario:

```
\dt public.*
```

And to get a list of schemas:

```
\dn
```

Note that `public` is the default schema when none is specified. Quoting the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PUBLIC):

> In the previous sections we created tables without specifying any
> schema names. By default such tables (and other objects) are
> automatically put into a schema named “public”. Every new database
> contains such a schema.

Using `\dt *.*` will output a long list of all tables in all schemas, including internal ones such as `pg_catalog`. The above can help with filtering.

Answer (score 1):

This can be used in automation scripts if you don't need all tables in all schemas:

```
  for table in $(psql -qAntc '\dt' | cut -d\| -f2); do
      ...
  done
```

Answer (score 1):

First, connect to `liferay` database:

```
\c liferay
```

Now, these list all tables of all schemas of `liferay` database:

```
\dt *.*
```

```
\dtS *.*
```

And, these list all tables of all schemas of `liferay` database in detail:

```
\dt+ *.*
```

```
\dtS *.*
```

And, these list all tables of `pg_catalog` and [public](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PUBLIC) schemas of `liferay` database:

```
\dtS
```

```
\dtS *
```

```
\dt *
```

And, these list all tables of `pg_catalog` and `public` schemas of `liferay` database in detail:

```
\dtS+
```

```
\dtS+ *
```

```
\dt+ *
```

And, this lists all tables of `public` schema of `liferay` database:

```
\dt
```

And, this lists all tables of `public` schema of `liferay` database in detail:

```
\dt+
```

And, these list all tables of `my_schema` schema of `liferay` database:

```
\dtS my_schema.*
```

```
\dt my_schema.*
```

Lastly, these list all tables of `my_schema` schema of `liferay` database in detail:

```
\dtS+ my_schema.*
```

```
\dt+ my_schema.*
```