# Get a list of all schemas that contain a certain table name

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, search, schema

I've looked at these questions:

- [postgres query to list all table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730228/postgres-query-to-list-all-table-names)
- [Psql list all tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445608/psql-list-all-tables)

But neither of them quite answer my question. I'm trying to search an entire PostgreSQL database and list the name of every schema in it that contains a "groups" table.

I'm thinking something like:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='groups';
```

But that's still missing how to get the containing schemas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_schema
  FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_name='yourtablename';
```